# How to get Last OrderId inside an Observer

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, event-observer, invoice

I am trying to get the last order id for an order so that I can create an invoice and shipment automatically but I can't seems to load the correct orderId to perform the action...

Here is how I am trying to load the orderId Observer.php

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
$orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

If the orderId is not present throw exception

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);    
if (!$order->getId()) {
        Mage::throwException("Order does not exist, for the Shipment process to complete");
    }
```

The problem is if I pass in a static orderId no exception is thrown

```
$orderIncrementId = '1100000023-4';
```

But when I try to load it through the Model I can't

Can anyone show me how to get the orderId for an order please?

Comment: What event are you using for the observer?

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff I am using `sales_order_invoice_register` for the Observer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Digging into it turned out, following solution works for me:

```
Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId()
```

Answer (score 13):

Get the latest order_id from the session like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
```

Here is also [another](http://importantmagento.blogspot.de/2012/08/magento-how-to-get-last-order-id.html)
 way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

To get the last order ID in Magento:

```
   $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
       ->setOrder('increment_id','DESC')
       ->setPageSize(1)
       ->getFirstItem();
    echo $orders->getEntityId()
```

Comment: This is correct, but there is an issue. `getFirstItem` loads the full collection. This could be a problem if you have a lot of orders. You should add a limit of 1 to the collection, to ensure that only one item is loaded.

Comment: I checked it. getFirstItem  would not show all the orders information. It shows only one order information.

Comment: Thanks @Marius I've ended up using `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();` but I am concious that there is a difference for orders created in Admin

Comment: I'm not saying it will show all the other orders information. I'm saying that it just retrieves them from the db and they are useless in this case. Check how `Varien_Data_Collection::getFirstItem` works. If you have 100k orders, just to retrieve the last order number this way it will take ages.

Comment: ok.That's right.